# insert binary img as html to pdf with node html-pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, binary, html-pdf

I try to insert a binary image to html to generate a PDF from html doc with the node module html-pdf.

According to other questions I tried the following code:

```
const pictureHtml = `<img src="data:image/png;base64","${binaryPicture}">`;
```

The picture is stored in mongoDB as datatype Binary.

If not possible with the module html-pdf, can you suggest a different module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**img src** must be base64string. We need convert **binaryPicture** to **base64string** .We have a code like this

```
var base64data = Buffer.from(binaryPicture, 'binary').toString('base64');
const pictureHtml = `<img src="data:image/png;base64","${base64data}">`;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I vote your answer up as soon as I am allowed to:)

Comment: I slightly changed the code to make it work:
    const base64data = Buffer.from(binaryPicture, 'binary').toString('base64');
    const pictureHtml = `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64data}">`;